# Ayuda con una validación en php

Tags: php

```
if(isset($_POST['enviar'])){

$_SESSION['nombre']=$_POST['firstname'];
$_SESSION['apellido']=$_POST['lastname'];
$_SESSION['direccion']=$_POST['direccion'];
$_SESSION['provincia']=$_POST['provincia'];
$_SESSION['ciudad']=$_POST['city'];
$_SESSION['zip']=$_POST['zip'];
$_SESSION['fono']=$_POST['phone'];
$_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email'];

echo '<script>window.location="../checkout2.php";</script>';

}

 $envio = 0;

//validacion sector

 if($_SESSION['ciudad'] == "quito" || $_SESSION['ciudad'] == 
  "sangolqui" || $_SESSION['ciudad'] == "cumbaya" || 
  $_SESSION['ciudad'] == "tumbaco"){
$sector =1;
}elseif ($_SESSION['provincia'] == "galapagos" ) {
$sector = 3;
}else{
$sector = 2;
}
 // validacion precio envio
 switch ($sector) {
case 1:
    $envio = 2.35;
    break;

case 2:
    $envio = 4.90;
    break;

case 3:
    $envio = 8.30;
    break;  
  }
```

tengo que poner que el precio del envio este validado por ciudad lo cual esta hecho pero necesito saber como poner con rangos si el peso es <=2000 va a tener un precio pero por cada 1000 que aumente el peso el precio se le va a sumar un valor y no se como hacer eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma sería la siguiente:

Luego del `switch` agregar el siguiente código:

```
$peso = 5500; //no veo la variable así que tomé esta como ejemplo
$adicional = 2; //precio que aumentará por cada 1000 de peso adicional a los 2000.

if ($peso > 2000) {
    $sobrepeso = $peso-2000;   //quito los 2000 de peso 'permitido'
    $aux = round($sobrepeso/1000);  //se obtiene el peso adicional en unidades, como es por
                                    //cada 1000 se realiza un redondeo así
    $envio += $aux * $adicional;
} else {
    //menor o igual a 2000, no se si entonces el precio es el del $envio nada más.
}
```

[Ejemplo de este código en Rextester](http://rextester.com/VJSGRZ63403)

Comment: Gracia amigo ya funciono si puedes dale una vuelta a la ultima pregunta que hice porfa

Answer (score 0):

Si calculas el aumeto es constante puedes crear una formula y ponerla en una funcion.

```
function calcularPrecio($peso, $factorAumento = 20,$precio = 100) {

  if ($peso > 200) {

    $precio = $precio + ($factorAumento * ceil(($peso - 200) / 1000));
  }

  return $precio;
}

echo calcularPrecio(900);
```

Tambien podrás puedes cambiar el factor de aumento y el precio inicial así:

```
echo calcularPrecio(900,100,2000);
```

Puedes cambiar [ceil](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ceil.php) por [floor](http://php.net/manual/es/function.floor.php) si fuese necesario de acuerdo a tus necesidades